# c libcurl ftp upload incomplete - 1 missing byte

Tags: c, curl, ftp, libcurl

I'm trying to use `libcurl` to test download and upload speeds. I have this weird issue on the upload side: 1 byte is systematically missing from the file I upload through `ftp`. Note that I'm not reading a file but rather I generate data on the fly in the `read_callback` of `curl` as all I'm interested in is the speed and note the data itself. See the code below, which is heavily based on this example: [libcurl chkspeed example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/chkspeed.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

#define UL_FTP_USR      "user"
#define UL_FTP_PWD      "password"
#define UL_TARGET_URL   "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/curl_upload_test"
#define UL_SIZE          1000000

long ul_total_bytes = 0;
static size_t read_callback_full(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    if(ul_total_bytes >= UL_SIZE) {
        printf("ul_total_bytes = %d\n", ul_total_bytes);
        return 0; // we stop upload at this point
    }

    char *pp = (char *) ptr;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < size*nmemb; i++)
    {
        pp[i] = i;
        ul_total_bytes += 1;
        if(ul_total_bytes >= UL_SIZE) {
            printf("ul_total_bytes = %d\n", ul_total_bytes);
            return i; // if we reach UL_SIZE_LIM we send last payload
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char *url = UL_TARGET_URL;
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;

  // init libcurl
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  // init the curl session
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

  // specify URL to put
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  
  //---------- FTP CREDENTIALS -----------
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERNAME, UL_FTP_USR);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, UL_FTP_PWD);
  //--------------------------------------
  
  // tell it to "upload" to the URL
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
  
  // bogus pointer. We don't read file, we generate data in read callback on the fly
  int p = 0;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, &p);

  // register read callback
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback_full);  
  
  // set the file size
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, UL_SIZE);

  // some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent field, so we provide one
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-speedchecker"); // useful here ???

  // execute the request!
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

  //if(CURLE_OK == res) {
    double val;

    // check for bytes downloaded
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD, &val);
    if((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
      printf("Data uploaded: %0.0f bytes.\n", val);
      
    // check for average upload speed
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &val);
    if((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
      printf("Average upload speed: %0.3f kbyte/sec.\n", val / 1024);

    // check for name resolution time 
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME, &val);
    if((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
      printf("Name lookup time: %0.3f sec.\n", val);
      
    // check for total time
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &val);
    if((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
      printf("Total time: %0.3f sec.\n", val);
      
  //}
  //else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while fetching '%s' : %s\n", url, curl_easy_strerror(res));
  //}

  // cleanup curl stuff
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

  // we're done with libcurl, so clean it up
  curl_global_cleanup();
  
  /*
  curl_version_info_data *data = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW); 
  printf("Version: %s\n", data->version);
  printf("Host: %s\n", data->host);
  printf("SSL-Version: %s\n", data->ssl_version);
  printf("Libz-Version: %s\n", data->libz_version);
  */

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get this output:

> ul_total_bytes = 1000000
>
> ul_total_bytes = 1000000
>
> Error while fetching 'ftp:// xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/curl_upload_test' : Transferred a partial file

But if I comment out the `if(CURLE_OK == res)` then I get this:

> ul_total_bytes = 1000000
>
> ul_total_bytes = 1000000
>
> Data uploaded: 999999 bytes.
>
> Average upload speed: 386.591 kbyte/sec.
>
> Name lookup time: 0.000 sec.
>
> Total time: 2.526 sec.
>
> Error while fetching 'ftp:// xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/curl_upload_test' : No error

And indeed, the file I find on my `ftp` is 999.999 bytes...

Here is version info:

> Version: 7.21.1
>
> Host: i586-common_3_0-linux-gnu
>
> SSL-Version: OpenSSL/1.0.0a
>
> Libz-Version: 1.2.3

The code has to run on an embedded system so I'm pretty much stuck with that version of `libcurl` which is supplied by the manufacturer.

Comment: this is for an ftp upload

Comment: that pointer is unused. It is the stream argument to read_callback_full function. It is normally used to pass information between callback and the rest of the app but I don't need it. However libcurl says that if you set it to NULL, the default read callback (fread to a file) will be used and I don't want that. The pointer I'm writing to is the right one. Data is transferred as expected except for 1 missing byte. Edit: See the doc here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html

Comment: For anyone interested, my original code was working file except one tiny mistake: In the read_callback_full, the "return i" instruction inside the for loop, should be "return i+1". That's where my missing byte was coming from. My bad.